# How do I remove one line of text within a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In the code below, I am trying to figure out a way to remove only the word `Welcome!`. What would be the most efficient way of doing this using jQuery?

```
<div>
  Welcome!
  <div class="lorem">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>blah blah</li>
    <li>blah blah</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends upon what criteria you want to remove that, and *only that*, text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its always the first node you can do this:

```
$("div").first().contents().first().remove();
```

Comment: You're selecting _all_ `div`s in the document.

Comment: @lanzz but only one content node. I still agree the first child of the first node is not always the one that should be removed.

Comment: he only has one div in his exmaple.

Comment: @chovy Nope, he has two actually.

Comment: That change won't do anything, except to do nothing in rare cases.

Comment: Sorry for the basic example. This did work after replacing 'div' with the actual name of the ID so THANK YOU chovy!

Comment: I still upvote as useful, even if the selector needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
var x = $('div:eq(0)').html().replace('Welcome!','');
$('div:eq(0)').html(x);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rbgBf/1/

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the prettiest, but this will work:

```
var parent = $(".lorem").parent();
​parent.html(parent.children());​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QsPYB/